# Getting sub class fields via reflection

Tags: java, reflection

I got 2 classes: `B` extends `A`.

I use `getDeclaratedFields()` on class `B`, and I don't get fields from class `A.

How can I get them?

Comment: Please share the code that you use for exporting from poi.  Most likely you are not closing the same.

Comment: sharing some code would give a better idea

Comment: Is the file saved as read-only? Is worksheet protected to disallow modifications of such kind?

Comment: How does this question related to Apache POI or Excel?

Comment: make a SSCCE for that (a Simple, Self Contained, Compileable Example) because without it, all we could do is guessing. How could we know what a 'getDeclaratedFields()' method would do without having your code that shows what it does?

Comment: @Bel The title asks for `sub` and the question asks for `super`, this is a contradiction, you should correct that!

Comment: @Bel if you have a new question you should [ask it as a new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask), rather than [editing an unrelated question to replace its content](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/15334310/revisions) (revision 10).  The comments on this question no longer make sense in light of your edits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

getDeclaredFields() returns fields which are declared by the class and not the super class.

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared
>   by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This
>   includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   fields, but excludes inherited fields.

Use getFields method to retrieve fields declared by class and super class.

> Specifically, if this Class object represents a class, this method
>   returns the public fields of this class and of all its superclasses

Read [Java Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Class#getSuperclass()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass%28%29) to access the super class of a classand get its fields too using [Class#getDeclaredFields()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields%28%29), repeat (recursively) until you reach [Object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) or a class of your choice where you want to stop.

Here is some sample code:

```
@Test
public void getDeclFieldsIncludingBase() {
    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>();
    getDeclFieldsIncludingBase(B.class, fields);
    for(Field f : fields) {
        System.out.println(f.getName());    
    }
}

private void getDeclFieldsIncludingBase(Class<?> cl, List<Field> fields) {
    Field[] declaredFields = cl.getDeclaredFields();
    for(Field f : declaredFields) {
        fields.add(f);
    }
    Class<?> superclass = cl.getSuperclass();
    if(! Object.class.equals(superclass)) {
        getDeclFieldsIncludingBase(superclass, fields);
    }
}
```

Example:

```
public class A {
    int a;
}
```

and

```
public class B extends A {
    int b;
}
```

The output should be

```
b
a
```